# Proving a function is a universal quadratic form

Tags: finite-fields, quadratic-forms

> If $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_q$ with $ab\neq 0$, then the function $f=\langle a,b\rangle :\mathbb{F}^2_q\to \mathbb{F}_q$ given by $$f(x,y)=ax^2+by^2$$ is a universal quadratic form.

In order to prove the previous statement, is it sufficient to prove that every element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the sum of two squares?

Comment: Does $\mathbb{F}_q$ denote a specific field?

Comment: not enough to use two squares. This is pigeon hole for a finite field.... For a fixed target $T,$ how many distinct values occur as $ T -a x^2   \; ?  \; \;$

Comment: here we use characteristic not 2